# jQuery SQlite - Client Side Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, browser, client-side

I am looking for JQuery or any other ways to store data on client-side (i.e. browser). I am preferring SQLite as it seems to have support as part of all the latest browsers supporting HTML5.

The plan is to basically to incrementally sync data from server-side & provide some search functionality on client-side. Not sure how much sophisticated search I can do with javascript.

Does anyone know of any such plugins or javascript solutions. Is it viable at all?

**UPDATE:** I am looking for sqlite based solution in browser as it provides good support for full text search. Also what are the limitations on size? I know sqlite3 performs well even for data more than 1GB. Does browser have any such size limitations? Is this possible at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HTML5" includes **localStorage** which might work for you, some great info on it can be had here:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Comment: that's true, but this is still at a nascent stage & I don't want to deal with all the cross-browser issues reg. "HTML5-localstorage". What I am looking for is an abstraction over all this. If the search term is not in localstorage then the javascript is clever enough to go over the wire & get the results from server...

Comment: For the cross browser issues, you can use an abstraction such as: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js as for going over the wire to get it, you are starting to cross the line into a framework really, it would need to know where and how to access the particular information etc. For that, something like http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ comes to mind, but I'm not sure how far down that path it goes, or how much it leaves for you to code. Worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you planning to store less than 5Mb.

You could use http://www.jstorage.info/

Its not SQL  but you can incrementally sync data, use it if it exsit or go to the server if it does not. Plus its cross browswer compatible and works on older browers but not with as much storage

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/)